# Javascript changing .href does not work

Tags: javascript, html, href

I want to add a dynamic link to an Id. Unfortunetaly, is simply does not replace the old href in the `<a>`-Tag. What is wrong with my code?

**My Javascript**

```
function setSocialLinks(current) {
    var sliderlinkA = document.getElementById("shareOnFacebook");
    sliderlinkA.href = "/test";
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<a id="shareOnFacebook" href="replaceit">Share on facebook</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in `DOMContentLoaded` callback. Or the `function` is at the end of `<body>`. Also, make sure you don't have duplicate id on the page

Comment: And how does `setSocialLinks` get called?

Comment: And how are you determining that it is/isn't being replaced?  For instance, if you view the source - you won't see that it's any different.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where and when is `setSocialLinks` being called is the biggest one...

Comment: It is called in a more complex loop. I know it is called because I've tested it with an alert.
  setSocialLinks(current);

Comment: Do you have more than one link with that same "id" value? Without seeing how or when the function is called, it's going to be hard to help. JavaScript and the DOM do work quite reliably, and there's nothing wrong with the code in your function.

Comment: The Id is reused, thats true. But not at the same time.

Comment: you can try  `sliderlinkA.setAttribute("href", "/test")`

Comment: call `console.log(document.getElementById("shareOnFacebook"))` in your function to see if it's returning an element (and that it's the correct one).

Comment: using the console.log it gives that as an output:
<a href="/test" id="shareOnFacebook">

So this seems to be fine. The clickable link is the old "replaceme" anyway.

Comment: Did you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call that function ..

Try `sliderlinkA.setAttribute('href', "http://example.com");`

Comment: its a numeric variable for something that is added later, after I fixed the href problem.

Comment: most likely you don't call the function because it should have worked

Comment: As I said, I do call the function :)

Comment: As @AdrianC.said :  
then show us entire code.. And what is "current"?

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be fine. Just make sure you are calling JavaScript function and it is defined in head tag or before calling the function. I have added your code in fiddle.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/osj81Lvn/
```

HTML

```
<a id="shareOnFacebook" href="replaceit">Share on facebook</a>

<button onclick="setSocialLinks();"/>Change URL</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function setSocialLinks(current) {
    var sliderlinkA = document.getElementById("shareOnFacebook");
    sliderlinkA.href = "/test";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have called the function in a loop, and that is working. I've tested it with an alert.

Comment: So, if your function is getting called properly, you need to take some precautions like: double check if there aren't duplicate id's and try debugging using browser console.

Comment: The browser console tells me everything is fine. If I use console.log to display the id in the function it shows me that everything is fine and teh <a href=""> is replaced. But it seems to get replaced again to the old "replaceme" href...

Comment: @Skalibran if href is getting reset after replacing, you need to check your code. It may be getting reset somewhere. You need to share your code. Or make sure you are not re-using the id of a tag anywhere on same page.